# In SSL how a certificate is matched/found in truststore?

Tags: ssl

In SSL how does it check whether there is a matching certificate in the trust-store? Is it by matching the fingerprint or the serial number?

I always thought it's by matching the fingerprint, but when I ran a java SSL debug following is what I got, and I couldn't see any fingerprint there.

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=XXXX
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: XXXX
  public exponent: XXXX
  Validity: [From: Mon Mar 16 22:48:10 UTC 2015,
               To: Sun Jun 14 22:48:10 UTC 2015]
  Issuer: CN=XXXX
  SerialNumber: [    XXXXXXX]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
 ...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
 ...

]
***
```

I hope this is not a duplicate question (I checked the suggested questions before posting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often, the `Certificate Authority Key Identifier` is marked as non-critical when present in the certificate to verify, and it's not even always present. You couldn't really rely on that as a fingerprint reference to use.

The verification is done by building a certification path, by chaining the Issuer DN (Distinguished Name) of the certificate to verify to the Subject DN of a CA certificate you trust.

This is described in the *CertPathBuilder*/*CertPathValidator* sections of the [Java PKI Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppB). (More generally, this follows RFC 3820, since there are other attributes to check too.)

Alternatively, you can also have an exact End Entity Certificate (not a CA certificate) directly in the truststore. In this case, an exact match with the certificate can be used.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't check whether there is a matching certificate. It checks whether there is a certificate whose subject equals the issuer of this certificate, and whose public key verifies the signature of this certificate.